# Replace image attributes for lazyload plugin (data-src)

Tags: posts, images, customization

I want to apply jquery lazyload plugin. For this to work I have to create a new attribute which is data-src place there the src value and then replace the src value with a specific value `'...nothing.gif'`.
I found a [solution on wordpress.org support](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-new-data-attribute-into-get_image_tag-function)

#### This is my adapted code -

```
function add_lazyload($content) 
{
    global $post;
    $search = '/src\=\"([^\s]+(?=\.(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png))\.\2)\"/';
    $content = replacer($content, $search, '/src/', 'data-original');
    $search = '/img\ class\=\"/';
    $content = replacer($content, $search, '/class\=\"/', 'class="lazy ');
    $search = '/alt/';
    $content = replacer($content, $search, '/alt/', 'src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/library/images/nothing.gif"');
    return $content;
}

function replacer($src, $search, $find, $replace)
{
    preg_match_all($search, $src, $result, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    foreach($result[0] as $entry)
    {
        $org = $entry[0];
        $rep = preg_replace($find, $replace, $entry[0]);
        $org = "/" .str_replace(array("=",":","/",".","-","_",'"',"'"," "),     array("\=","\:","\/","\.","\-","\_",'\"',"\'","\ "), $org). "/";
        $src = preg_replace($org, $rep, $src);
    }
return $src;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'add_lazyload');
```

The problem with this code is that it replaces every `alt` string (for example in a paragraph) with `.../library/images/nothing.gif`, not just the alt image attribute.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

instead of replacing the alt tag you could [add-an-attribute-to-a-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983029/regex-add-an-attribute-to-a-tag-in-html-php)

```
function add_lazyload($content) {
     $dom = new DOMDocument();
     @$dom->loadHTML($content);


     foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {  
         $oldsrc = $node->getAttribute('src');
         $node->setAttribute("data-original", $oldsrc );
         $newsrc = ''.get_template_directory_uri().'/library/images/nothing.gif';
         $node->setAttribute("src", $newsrc);
     }
     $newHtml = $dom->saveHtml();
     return $newHtml;
}
```

note: i didn't quite tested this code, so be careful :)

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution works great!. Just one thing, you are missing a semicolon after $newHtml = $dom->saveHtml(). Thanks again!

Comment: ahhh! you're right! :))

Comment: Be careful here, if you use this on a fragment of a post it may mess with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: DOMDocument is expensive

Answer (score 7):

I modified peteroak's excellent solution to convert to utf-8 and stripped the doctype, html, and body from the ouput.

```
function add_lazyload($content) {

    $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($content);

    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {  
        $oldsrc = $node->getAttribute('src');
        $node->setAttribute("data-original", $oldsrc );
        $newsrc = ''.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/nothing.gif';
        $node->setAttribute("src", $newsrc);
    }
    $newHtml = preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $dom->saveHTML()));
    return $newHtml;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_lazyload');
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just about to comment this problem and found your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I added some features to Shieeets solution:

- srcset support (changes srcset to data-srcset)
- noscript fallback (displays original image)
- video/embed/iframe support (Youtube and co)
- additional hook to affect thumbnails (in addition to post images)
- classes "lazy" and "lazy-hidden" are added automatically

Here is the PHP code:

```
// Lazyload Converter
function add_lazyload($content) {

    $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($content);

    // Convert Images
    $images = [];

    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {  
        $images[] = $node;
    }

    foreach ($images as $node) {
        $fallback = $node->cloneNode(true);

        $oldsrc = $node->getAttribute('src');
        $node->setAttribute('data-src', $oldsrc );
        $newsrc = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/placeholder.gif';
        $node->setAttribute('src', $newsrc);

        $oldsrcset = $node->getAttribute('srcset');
        $node->setAttribute('data-srcset', $oldsrcset );
        $newsrcset = '';
        $node->setAttribute('srcset', $newsrcset);

        $classes = $node->getAttribute('class');
        $newclasses = $classes . ' lazy lazy-hidden';
        $node->setAttribute('class', $newclasses);

        $noscript = $dom->createElement('noscript', '');
        $node->parentNode->insertBefore($noscript, $node); 
        $noscript->appendChild($fallback); 
    }


    // Convert Videos
    $videos = [];

    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe') as $node) {
        $videos[] = $node;
    }

    foreach ($videos as $node) {  
        $fallback = $node->cloneNode(true);

        $oldsrc = $node->getAttribute('src');
        $node->setAttribute('data-src', $oldsrc );
        $newsrc = '';
        $node->setAttribute('src', $newsrc);

        $classes = $node->getAttribute('class');
        $newclasses = $classes . ' lazy lazy-hidden';
        $node->setAttribute('class', $newclasses);

        $noscript = $dom->createElement('noscript', '');
        $node->parentNode->insertBefore($noscript, $node); 
        $noscript->appendChild($fallback); 
    }

    $newHtml = preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $dom->saveHTML()));
    return $newHtml;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_lazyload');
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'add_lazyload');
```