# Replace image scr with it's surrounding href

Tags: filters, the-content

I'm trying to add a filter to the content to replace the src of all images in the content with it's surrounding href link. Any ideas how to go about this?

The only thread I could find that came close was this: [Replace image attributes for lazyload plugin (data-src)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60792/replace-image-attributes-for-lazyload-plugin-data-src)

Comment: This sounds like something you'd want for printing a page - to pick the highest-res version of an image - so maybe there's a printing plugin that'll do this for you. Doesn't the answer you've linked to help - that shows you how to parse an HTML page into a DOM so you can traverse it and e.g. find all images, then check their parents, then copy the URL if it's an image, etc.?

Answer (score -1):

Use this for example in the loop

```
$new_url = '<img src="http://www.google.nl';
$content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
$content = preg_replace("/(<img[^>]*src *= *[\"']?)([^\"']*)/i", $new_url,  $content);
```